# Obtaining hard, overlapping clusters using non-negative matrix factorization

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction, matrix, non-negative-matrix-factorization

From my understanding non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) provides a natural way to obtain soft clusters from a non-negative $n$x$m$ data matrix $X$. NMF decomposes $X$ into two non-negative matricies: an $n$x$d$ matrix $W$ and a $d$x$m$ matrix $H$, where $d$ is the number of factors chosen for the decomposition and usually $d<<m$.

If $X$ is a matrix of $n$ observations each with $m$ features, then each row in $W$ provides the factor loadings for an observation. From my understanding, each factor from $1$ to $d$ can be treated as a cluster label. Then the factor loadings for a particular observation can be treated as the strength of association between the observation and the corresponding factor (cluster).

For example, if $d=4$ and the factor loadings for observation $i$ are \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1.2 & 0.3 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}
then observation $i$ is associated with factor 1 with a score of 0, factor 2 with a score of 1.2, factor 3 with a score of 0.3 and factor 4 with a score of 0.5.

Currently, I normalize the factor loadings for each observation, so that it sums to 1, and I treat the resulting values as percentages corresponding to 'how much' the observation is in each cluster.

In the example above, this would give the factor loading
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0.6 & 0.15 & 0.25
\end{bmatrix}
and I interpret this as observation $i$ is 0% associated with factor 1, 65% associated with factor 2, 15% associated with factor 3 and 25% associated with factor 4.

I want to be able to extract hard, but overlapping cluster assignments from $W$. My current approach is to choose an arbitrary percentage cutoff (say 20%), so that any factor loading above 20% counts as an assignment, and any loading below 20% counts as no assignment. So in the above example, observation $i$ would be associated only with cluster 2 and 4.

**My question:** What is a more principled way of extracting hard, overlapping clusters using NMF?

I suspect that both the percentage interpretation from the normalizing procedure is faulty and the arbitrary thresholding is not robust to factors that have high loading across many observations (in other words, big clusters that aren't informative) and this will lead to suboptimal cluster assignments.

Comment: Why use NMF? For cluster analysis some say the advantage of the two-step method appears to be in identifying the number of clusters https://www.researchgate.net/post/Two-step_cluster_analysis_hierarchical_or_k-means

Comment: @Carl My particular problem requires the possibility of multiple cluster assignments for a given observation. I was told that NMF is a good fit since it finds soft clusters.

Comment: The link I provided finds the optimal number of overlapping clusters with multiple assignments by minimizing BIC or AIC.

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7555988/